# What is the everyday fay?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

*Part of the [everyday object series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=body%3A%22everyday+object+series%22+is%3Aquestion)*

> I present to you: the everyday fay.
>   Its ancestor was born on the very first day.
>   It lives alone, but can work well in a team,
>   Only comes alive when its foot is engulfed in a stream.
>   Its head is what's most important to us,
>   The material therein is almost superfluous;
>   That which comes out, that is the prize.
>   Incorporeal, yet it made us modernize.

What is this everyday fay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is

> A lightbulb

Its ancestor was born on the very first day.

> The sun, our world’s original light source

It lives alone, but can work well in a team,

> One bulb per socket, but multi-socket fixtures provide more light

Only comes alive when its foot is engulfed in a stream.

> A “stream” of electricity

Its head is what's most important to us,

> As that’s where the light comes from

The material therein is almost superfluous;

> Light bulbs are basically vacuums inside, other than the slenderest filament

That which comes out, that is the prize.

> The light,  of course.

Incorporeal, yet it made us modernize.

> The light bulb spurred electric power distribution grids and all that came with ready availability of electricity to households.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a

> transistor

I present to you: the everyday fay.
Its ancestor was born on the very first day.

> perhaps this references the electron?

It lives alone, but can work well in a team,

> A transistor is standalone, but works well in a circuit

Only comes alive when its foot is engulfed in a stream.

> I think this refers to the need of current (a stream of electrons) for it to operate

Its head is what's most important to us,
The material therein is almost superfluous;

> the material of a transistor can vary, but doesn't affect how it works

That which comes out, that is the prize.
Incorporeal, yet it made us modernize.

> We are modernized because of the transistor

Comment: Very nice idea, but not what I was thinking about.